# How does spray find resources - e.g. javascript

Tags: spray

It was simple to build my first servlet with spray-io.

But the recources referenced in the header are never found.

< head>
...
< script src="javascript/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>
...
< / head>

In which directory does one have to put those recsources, or how can spray be directed to look up there?

Simple question, but I could not figure out.

Many thankx

Girgl

Answer (score 10):

With Spray routing, I use these directives -

```
pathPrefix("css") { get { getFromResourceDirectory("css") } } ~
pathPrefix("js") { get { getFromResourceDirectory("js") } } ~
```

"css" and "js" have to be in `src/main/resources` directory

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spray routing, then it should be easy, just provide a route for your static resources. For example you can do the following:

Let's say that your static resources are in `/css`, `/js` and `/img` folders:

```
def staticPrefixes = List("css", "js", "img") map { pathPrefix(_) } reduce { _ | _ }
```

with `pathPrefix` you are making each path a prefix of an unmatched path. Then you need a directive to extract path to static file from the request, for example you can do it like this:

```
def stripLeadingSlash(path: String) = if (path startsWith "/") path.tail else path

val staticPath =
  staticPrefixes &
  cache(routeCache()) &
  extract(ctx ⇒ stripLeadingSlash(ctx.request.uri.path.toString))
```

then construct your route which would manage your resources:

```
val staticRoutes =
    get {
      staticPath { path ⇒
        getFromResource(path.toString)
      }
    }
```