# Spray: how to deal with file path inside routing while serving html pages

Tags: html, file, scala, path, spray

I have a Scala-Spray application/project and I'm trying to serve an HTML page when I select a certain route.

In this HTML page, I need to "include" some files from my path, but I'm missing something since I can't load them properly, as in this example (js file, but it could be an image as well).

Here's the code I wrote to "load" a javascript file in my html page:

```
        path("myPath") {
      respondWithMediaType(`text/html` ) {
        complete {
          var html =
          """
            <html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///home/myUser/Desktop/myFile.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    ...
                });
                </script>
            </head>
```

How can I refer to my "local" files in order to load them in the HTML page?

What Am I missing?

Thanks in advance

FF

Comment: I guess this link can make sense for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010276/how-does-spray-find-resources-e-g-javascript

Comment: Thank you Michael for the hint, but I'm still confused about the solution I need... I do not understand how to "map" these file in order to have fill correctly my src tag

Comment: The src attribute is parsed on the client which then makes a new request to the server (or any other server). The usual solution is to use relative URLs and serve things from well-known directories on the same server. Is this really a spray question? I.e. in how far is this different from what you would do with a static page which is uploaded to any hoster?